# How to recreate singleton instance in c#

Tags: c#, .net, singleton

I have a singleton class, it is reading config file.

```
public sealed class SettingsHelper
    {
        private static readonly SettingsHelper _Instance = new SettingsHelper();

        static SettingsHelper()
        {
        }

        public static SettingsHelper Instance
        {
            get
            {
                return _Instance;
            }
        }

        private NameValueCollection _SettingsSection = null;

        public SettingsHelper()
        {
            _SettingsSection = new NameValueCollection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings);           
        }

        .....
    }
}
```

But if config file getting changed the singleton do not picking up the change.
Is there any way to recreate the instance of singleton(call its constructor) or i should create separate method which will be reinitiating the instance of singleton?

Comment: Do you mean changing the config file at runtime?

Comment: Are you just storing a copy of AppSettings? What advantage does this provide over accessing ConfigurationManager directly when you need it?

Comment: @MikeSW you mean DI Container for SettingsHelper?

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to throw away the very first purpose of singleton pattern. A singleton is there, just to prevent any other code from instantiating a new instance of that class. To make a singleton class, you should not have public constructors at all. You already have a public constructor.

I encourage you to read the first line, just the first line of [this Wikipedia article about Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

What you're trying to do, is called cache dependency in C#. You're trying to cache Web.config's app settings and you are dependent on Web.config's change. You should search that.

Comment: Do you think that solution by @joe, with public method not so good idea?

Comment: Yeah, that's also a good idea. But that's explicit. That's on-demand. You don't want that. You want your cache to be updated automatically. So it won't work for you.

Comment: Looks like that will be something more complex, I mean i need to write some mo lines of code :) in order to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

It will be better to create a separate method inside your singleton class to read the settings again. Obviously, with this approach, you will have to call this method from your code.

Comment: `SettingsHelper()` is not a method.  That looks like a constructor.

Comment: Very true! Changed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Recreating a singleton is abad idea - references to the 'old' singleton will stay.
So it's no longer a singelton!

In your case I would create new settings. Why not make a public method `LoadSettings()`  and call that?

```
public sealed class SettingsHelper
{
    private static readonly SettingsHelper _Instance = new SettingsHelper();
    private NameValueCollection _SettingsSection = null;

    // ...

    private SettingsHelper()
    {
        LoadSettings()
    } 


    public void LoadSettings()
    {
        _SettingsSection = new NameValueCollection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings);           
    }

    .....
}
```

}

BTW: make `SettingsHelper()` private...

Comment: It is exactly what i was going to do but was thought that there are could be another codeless or more clever approach.

Comment: @sreginogemoh: I think more simple isn't possible :)